# Why does php return an error for file not found when trying to include it?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I have a WordPress page where I want to display a an external script.. I found that I can use a plugin to insert php code in the page, and the code would call the external files, specifically the index.php, that would execute the rest.

I think I have done the steps right, but now when I load the page, it throws all kinds of errors showing me that some files can't be included because the don't exist, in the folder, yet they do.

To test and prove, I can just use the script outside WordPress and it runs well...is when I type http://example.com/folder..I access it well.

What could be wrong?.
Any help would be appreciated.

PS.am really a newbie to code, I mostly perform these actions from tutorials to arrive at my goal..please don't be so technical.

Thanks.

The image shows the different error messages on my localhost:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Try absolute paths

*You* know where the file is, but your website doesn't. It is most likely looking for libs/functions.php *in the wrong folder*. You're smart enough to find libs/functions.php, but your site is looking for it in the folder it is presently in and nowhere else. Try using an absolute path like "http://example.com/blah/libs/functions".

### If that fails, check permissions

When it comes to error messages, WordPress doesn't know the difference between a file that doesn't exist and a file that exists, but it doesn't have permission to see. Even if the file is there, WordPress needs to be able to see it.

Comment: _"Try using an absolute path like `http://example.com/blah/libs/functions`."_ - that is likely bad advice here, because an include via the file system, and an include via HTTP, do _very_ different things.